# primary key mvc entitityframework model error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

This one's driving me nuts.

I have a table with several columns and a Primary Key (bigint, not null)

I have VS create a model of it

```
public long ParcelRangeID { get; set; }
..
..
```

Then I create Controller and View. When I use the Create View to create a new record, on db.SaveChanges the troubles start: (I have included the field in my view as HiddenFor)

- With no further changes; I get a Required ID is missing error. (also when I use the DataAnnotations  `[Key]`, `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]`
- When I use `[Bind(Exclude="ParcelRangeID")]`  i get the DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

How can I insert a new record and have the required ID generated automatically without the error?

***Edit***

Here's the controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create(ParcelRange parcelrange)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.ParcelRange.Add(parcelrange);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(parcelrange);
            }
```

And the model:

```
 public partial class ParcelRange
    {
        public ParcelRange()
        {
            this.PickupAddressID = -1;
            this.OrganizationID = -1;
            this.DepotID = -1;
            this.IsVTG = 0;
            this.IsInternal = 0;
            this.IsInterCompany = 0;
            this.UpdateCount = 0;
            this.IsActive = 1;
            this.Modified = DateTime.Now.Date;
            this.Created = DateTime.Now.Date;
            this.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now.Date;
            this.ValidTo = DateTime.MaxValue;
        }

        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public long ParcelRangeID { get; set; }
        public long NdswCustomerID { get; set; }
        public long PickupAddressID { get; set; }
        public long OrganizationID { get; set; }
        public long DepotID { get; set; }
        public string ParcelRangePrefix { get; set; }
        public string ParcelNumberStart { get; set; }
        public string ParcelNumberEnd { get; set; }
        public byte IsVTG { get; set; }
        public byte IsInternal { get; set; }
        public byte IsInterCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVer { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public int UpdateCount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
        public byte IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

***Edit (2)***

And finally the (default) view autogenerated

```
@model MvcApplication1.ParcelRange

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ParcelRangeID)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ParcelRange</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NdswCustomerID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NdswCustomerID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NdswCustomerID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PickupAddressID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PickupAddressID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PickupAddressID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrganizationID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrganizationID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganizationID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepotID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepotID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepotID)
        </div>

@*        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParcelRangePrefix)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParcelRangePrefix)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParcelRangePrefix)
        </div>*@

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParcelNumberStart)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParcelNumberStart)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParcelNumberStart)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParcelNumberEnd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParcelNumberEnd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParcelNumberEnd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsVTG)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsVTG)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsVTG)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsInternal)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInternal)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsInternal)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsInterCompany)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInterCompany)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsInterCompany)
        </div>

@*        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Created)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Created)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Created)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Modified)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Modified)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Modified)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UpdateCount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateCount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UpdateCount)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidFrom)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidFrom)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidFrom)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValidTo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidTo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValidTo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
        </div>*@

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

***Edit (3)***
Database script for the table:

```
USE [DPDCDB_ODS]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ParcelRange]    Script Date: 16-6-2014 15:50:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange](
    [ParcelRangeID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NdswCustomerID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PickupAddressID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DepotID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ParcelRangePrefix]  AS (left([ParcelNumberStart],(4))),
    [ParcelNumberStart] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ParcelNumberEnd] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsVTG] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IsInternal] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IsInterCompany] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RowVer] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ValidTo] [date] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ParcelRange] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParcelRangeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [DATA]
) ON [DATA]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [NdswCustomerID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [PickupAddressID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [OrganizationID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [DepotID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsVTG]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsInternal]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsInterCompany]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Modified]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [UpdateCount]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ValidFrom]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT (CONVERT([date],'9999-12-31')) FOR [ValidTo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ParcelRange] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsActive]
GO
```

***Edit (4)***

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0, will try to update to a higher version.

***Edit (5)***
Updated to EF 6.1, same problem
This is my connectionstring:

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\DEV;initial catalog=DPDCDB_ODS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient
```

Comment: can you post your controller code? or the section where you are calling the db.SaveChanges()?

Comment: Post your entire model for ParcelRange.

Comment: Can you post your view code? I feel like the model binding is not done properly.

Comment: StoreGeneratedPattern : Identity. Update from database I have tried several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"(I have included the field in my view as HiddenFor)"`

As it is a *database-generated* primary key, in a `create` view it has no initial value and you should not be using a `HiddenFor` to hold that property. Just delete that `HiddenFor`.

If you use the scaffolding wizards to create EF controllers you should note the primary key is never present in the `create` views.

### Update: http://robjoosentest.azurewebsites.net/parcelranges

I took the table script provided, created a database, exported it to Azure, created a VS 2013 MVC web application and then the EF model-based controller and views for the table. I then published it to Azure and it works just fine (well done Microsoft, let's see anyone do that with Amazon S3 in 5 mins flat!) :). I suspect it is the version of one of your libraries (maybe EF version). Otherwise it may be a side effect of other database activity on your web app.

Comment: Tried that just now, and it results in the DBUpdateConcurrencyException on db.SaveChanges();

(Removed the full line of code for HiddenFor btw)

Comment: With a clean project, only the model (ParcelRangeClass) I created a new controller and views (NExt-Next-Finish) and agian, there's the DBUpdateConcurrencyException. A remark: The class has some fields that represent some computed fields (DateTime is inserted by the database) and there are some constraints in the database (Default values)

Comment: Therefor I added the defaults part in the ParcelRange class constructor as a test.

Comment: @Rob Joosen: I have taken your table, created a database (on Azure), created a new MVC project an EF model with views and `create` works just fine. http://robjoosentest.azurewebsites.net/parcelranges What version of EF are you using?

Comment: How cool is that... I don't have the environment available now, but will check tomorrow (CET) Thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: Hm, Updated to EF 6.x and still having the same problem....

Edited te original question with the connectionstring

Comment: OK, you were on EF5. That makes sense as EF 5 was badly flawed. Did you blow away the EDMX and recreate it completely?

Comment: @Rob Joosen: Good choice. I often blow away complete projects and merge what I need. Keeps it fresh :)

Comment: No, but started a new project, MVC 5 - EF 6.1, Next Next Finish: and again the DBUpdateConcurrencyException on Create New -> SaveChanges. This is getting pretty annoying..

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question to our DBA, he immediately pointed me in the right direction.

There are triggers on this specific table.....These triggers cause the DBUpdateConcurrencyException. We disabled these triggers and the Insert went well

We now have to find out how to mimick the triggers in C# or use STP to update/insert records with EF.

Thanks for your support!